# Resize all images with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can I resize all images using javascript?
I tried this:

```
var images = document.getElementByTagName('img')
images.max_width = '100px'
images.max_height = '100px'
```

But it didn't work. Then I tried `document.images` instead of `document.getElementByTagName('img')` but it also didn't work.

Also, I don't want to resize the images using CSS.
Please reply.

Thanks.

Comment: It's document.getElement**s**ByTagName, and it returns a list you need to iterate over. also it's `img.style.maxWidth`

Comment: Also, trying to set arbitrary properties named `max_width` and `max_height` isn't going to achieve anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use forEach(), or use for(), to loop through all images.

```
// select all images
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
// loop through all images
images.forEach(function (img, i) {
  img.style.maxWidth('100px');
  img.style.maxHeight('100px');
});
```

If you do not want the images changing width/height, then give them a width:100px; and height:100px;